# Spring Rest Error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using rest services with spring data . when i get data from single table its return proper result in json format . but when i use many to many association between entities using hibernate i am getting an un acceptable result with following error in chrome's console .

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

My result looks like there just one row repeating itself , and its a particularly that field which is being used in new generated table by association.

```
[{"id":7,"name":"Milk pack","description":"haleeb","imageUrl":"milk.jpg","price":350.00,"category":null,"orderDetail":[]},{"id":8,"name":"oil","description":"olive oil ","imageUrl":"/resources/uploads/olive.png","price":670.00,"category":null,"orderDetail":[{"id":263,"productlist":[{"id":10,"name":"Mobile","description":"awesome design, slim design ","imageUrl":"/static/uploads","price":34569.00,"category":null,"orderDetail":[{"id":263,"productlist":[{"id":10,"name":"Mobile","description":"awesome design, slim design ","imageUrl":"/static/uploads","price":34569.00,"category":null,"orderDetail":[{"id":263,"productlist":[{"id":10,"name":"Mobile","description":"awesome design, slim design ","imageUrl":"/static/uploads","price":34569.00,"category":null,"orderDetail":[{"id":263,"productlist":[{"id":10,"name":"Mobile","description":"awesome design, slim design 
.
.
.and so on
```

My entities are following

**Product table**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productlist")
private List<OrderDetail> orderDetail =new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
```

**OrderDetail table**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="order_detail_productlist",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="order_detail_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="productlist_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private Set<Product> productlist = new HashSet<Product>();
```

I am using spring data jpa repository to get them

```
List<Product> findAll();
```

Note: which products those are not ordered yet that are working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Problem is solved by using jackson 2.0 documentation

by Adding following annotation or OrderDetail table

```
@JsonBackReference
```

it breaks loop and show result properly

Comment: and what all that means? what annotation broke the code and why @JsonBackReference resolved the problem&

Answer (score 2):

You need the all log for the information, it maybe cause by loop when with `jackson`. So you need add `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.Please see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387`